# Cannot find symbol: @XmlInverseReference

Tags: java, xml, web-services, eclipselink, moxy

I am following the tutorial at http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html. I copy and paste the files into netbeans (making sure it works as provided). `@XmlInverseReference` shows compile error. Besides `import javax.persistence.*` do I need to import something else?

Answer (score 1):

`@XmlInverseReference` is an annotation from [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) used to denote a bidirectional relationship, you'll need to [download EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/2.4.php) too to use it. For more information see [a further article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html) from the same blog you linked which covers the annotations in further depth.